# How to download only wanted data in database table(html) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, database, ejs

I'm having trouble downloading the data from the table that I only wanted. I have a `ejs` file that retrieves data and show it in a table. and then I added some `input:search` that search through the data in the table and only display that matches the string in the search bar. I already have this `download` button that only download the whole table what I want is to only download what is shown in the table once I uses search bar.

I tried searching in the net but all I can see is download for static table data/without search query.
this is what I followed on how to download table to xls file https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript/

this is my `index.ejs`

```
<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<hr>
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <% if(details!=null) { %>
    <table class="text-center table table-striped table-hover table-dark table-fixed">
      <thead>
        <tr class="table-primary" style="color:black; font-weight:bold;">
          <th scope="col">Route</th>
          <th scope="col">Origin </th>
          <th scope="col">Destination</th>
          <th scope="col">Estimated Time of Arrival </th>
          <th scope="col">Date </th>
          <th scope="col">Time</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <% details.forEach(function(item){ %>
        <tbody id="myTable">

          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= item.route%>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= item.origin %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= item.destination%>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= item.estimatedTimeOfArrival %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= item.date%>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= item.time%>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <% }) %>
    </table>
    <% } %>

</div>
<button onclick="exportTableToCSV('data.csv')">Download Table</button>
</div>
```

this is the code that filter the table in search query

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

I expect that once I use the search bar and it shows only the data that I wanted after that once I click the download button it will only download the shown data not the whole data in the table.

for example I search number `1` in the table it will only display all data that has number `1` and so that's what I only wanted to download, but the case is after clicking the `download` it includes all the number not just `1`
Thank you in advance.